# using structure pointer in scanf doesnt work even with syntax &(struct_pointer->struct_var)

Tags: c, struct, scanf

(There was a similar question but the answer given doesn't work)
There is no warning. But after entering values, segmentation fault appears.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  int a;
  char b;
}PO;

PO *P[1000];

int main()
{
  scanf("%d%c",&(P[0]->a),&(P[0]->b));
}
```

Comment: `PO P[1000];...
  scanf("%d%c", &P[0].a, &P[0].b);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> PO *P[1000];
> ```

defines an array of 1000 **pointers** to `PO` structures.

Written like that it would probably be clearer:

```
PO* P[1000];  // <-- P is an array of 1,000 pointers to PO
```

What you probably want is a preallocated array of structures, not pointers to those, e.g.:

```
PO Data[1000];
```

In this case, you can read data into it with code like this:

```
scanf("%d%c", &(Data[0].a), &(Data[0].b));
```

Or, if you still want an array of pointers, you should allocate each structure using `malloc()` and then `free()` it after use.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
typedef struct
{
 int a;
 char b;
}PO_t;

int main(void)
{
 unsigned int i=0;
 PO_t PO[1000]; //create a 1000 struct of the type PO
 PO_t* ptr[1000]; //create 1000 pointers to struct of type PO_t

 for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
 {
  ptr[i]=&PO[i]; //or ptr[i]=&PO[0] if you want 1000 pointers to a single struct
 }

 for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
 {
      scanf("%d%c\n",&(PO[i].a),&(PO[i].b));
 }

 for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
 {
      printf("%d%c\n",ptr[i]->a),ptr[i]->b));
 }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depends.If you have a large stack that can hold so many struct and ptrs